# Networked GUI handler for binary protocol

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, network-programming

Alright, so I created a Client and Server that manipulates a Map via a GUI interface using a text based protocol. The handler below was used to create a "work order" to manipulate the GUI on a separate thread from the network communications.

```
class RemoteInputHandler implements Runnable,SharedVariables
{


 @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            String input = netComm.reader.readLine();
            while (input != null)
            {
                // Make a separate copy of the input string 
                String inputCopy = input;
                // Post a work order to process the command on the GUI thread
                Platform.runLater(() ->
                {
                    handleRemote(inputCopy);
                });
                // Get the next remote input
                input = netComm.reader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

    }
```

This pulls the next line of input from the server without freezing up the GUI. I then use the input in the handleRemote() method with a scanner to determine what is done with the input. The string retrieved from the reader looked something like "put key value". I'd then get the first word "put", using a scanner, to get the "command" and use a switch statement to determine how the GUI / Map should be updated on the client and server side respectively.

I'm doing another GUI based program that uses a binary protocol instead, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle the information in the same way as I did with the readLine() above. Is there a way to do this? Am i thinking about it the wrong way? I thought I could just get all of the bytes into an array, but I'm having trouble even figuring that out.

I could really use a hint! Thank you!

Comment: What is netComm.reader?  Have you considered using a library like [Netty](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-5.x.html)?  Netty allows you to build a pipeline of handlers to process incoming data.

Comment: readLine() ready ASCII characters up to the NewLine charcter. So that provides a kind of 'framing' for each line. If you process binary data streams, you have to use a different framing to know where a single frame starts end ends... e.g.: Encode the length of the message first or defined a termination character like NewLine that will not occure in the message itself. (Was that your question?)